# vuejs2 - two npm packages have same prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am stuck at one point here. I am building a multilingual website for which I have used the package vue-multilanguage https://github.com/leonardovilarinho/vue-multilanguage
I have registered the package in my main.js as below -

```
import MultiLanguage from 'vue-multilanguage'
import resources from './resources/resources'
Vue.use(MultiLanguage, resources)
```

to set a language dynamically, the code I have used is

```
this.language = fr //example.
```

It works like a charm, no issues..

Now, the problem arises when I use a datetime picker from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker.

I register it in my component as

```
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
export default {
  name: 'UserCustEmpRelationship',
  components: {
    Datepicker
    },
}
```

Now this datepicker also has a prop called language. Coincidentally my multilanguage package also has a data property called language(I set it to this.language).. My guess is that the datepicker is confusing the two language and giving the error as -

The data property "language" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.

found in

--->

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: This actually makes no sense and there is a collision that's going on here that shouldn't be, but the mixin is registering the property `language` on every single component that is rendered. Tough one.

Comment: that's the problem.. it is registering the property language on every component :(